# Converting a list of numbers into 2d rectangular/polygonal representations with Elixir

Tags: matrix, geometry, elixir, 2d, game-physics

I have a list of integers representing a 2D graph/grid (matrix?) that is rendered from the top-left corner down, where width = w and height = h.

The list looks like:

```
list = [4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 6, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]
```

Items in the list > 0 represent a wall, while items that == 0 represent an open space.

I am trying to write a function that iterates through this list and returns the smallest number of rectangles (top-left x,y and width/height) representing all of the walls, for the purpose of handling collisions with objects within the walls.

For a list of w = 4 h = 4:

```
square_list = [
        8, 8, 8, 8, 
        8, 8, 8, 8, 
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        7, 7, 7, 7
       ]
```

`return_rectangles(square_list, w, h)` would return:

```
[
   # Note: the y value increases positively as we move downward
   %{top_left_x: 0, top_left_y: 0, width: 4, height: 2}, # first two rows (the 8s)
   %{top_left_x: 0, top_left_y: 3, width: 4, height: 1}  # second row (the 7s)
]
```

I also have to handle cases of vertical walls / irregular rows of rectangles, e.g.:

```
tall_list = [
        8, 8, 8, 8, 
        8, 8, 8, 8, 
        8, 0, 0, 8,
        8, 0, 0, 8,
        8, 8, 0, 8,
        7, 7, 7, 7
       ]
```

Wondering if I should still pursue rectangular abstractions of this list or if I should go for polygons instead

I've started off by converting the list into a stream of tuples containing indices and removing the 0 value items, thinking that an item's index indicates its place on the grid and that 0 values are irrelevant (maybe it would be easier to calculate open space (space = 0) rather than closed, actually...):

```
  def convert_list_to_indexed_tuples(list) do
    # Creates a stream with index from a given list,
    # outputing {item, index}
    with_indices = Stream.with_index(list)

    # remove zero values
    # returns a stream that as a list looks like [{item, index}, ...], e.g. [{8, 112}, ...]
    Stream.take_while(with_indices, fn {item, _index} ->
      tile != 0
    end)
  end
```

I then decided to post this here to crowdsource a solution as I work towards one, as it has been a long time since I've done graph math. Maybe I should treat the list like a matrix?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected output for `[8,8,8,0]` input? Also, in the first example, the second element should be `top_left_x: 0` not  `top_left_x: 3`.

Comment: Good catch -- expected output for list = [8,8,8,0] where grid w = 4 and h = 1 would be [%{top_left_x: 0, top_left_y: 0, w: 3, h: 1}]

Comment: I meant with `w = 2` and `h = 2`.

Comment: I am thinking separate rectangles for these overlapping cases, e.g. something like: 
[
  %{top_left_x: 0, top_left_y: 0, w: 1, h: 2},
  %{top_left_x: 1, top_left_y: 1, w: 1, h: 1}
] 
if parsing vertical rectangles first